# How to add to generic function print the message method print.message?

Tags: r, r-package, r-box

Suppose `getwd()` yields `"C:/Users/Tom/Documents/Tom_Levers_Git_Repository"`.

In this repository, I have directory `TomLeversRBox`.

In this box, I have modules `calculate_probability.R` and `print.message.R`.

In the module `calculate_probability.R`, I have the following function.

```
box::use(./print.message)
box::use(stats[pnorm])

#' @export
calculate_probability <- function() {
    message <- paste("Probability: ", round(pnorm(1.644854, 0, 1, lower.tail = TRUE), 2), sep = "")
    class(message) <- "message"
    return(message)
}
```

In the module `print.message.R`, I have the following function.

```
#' @export
print.message <- function(message) {
    cat(message)
}
```

In RStudio's console, I run `install.packages("box")`.

I run `box::use(TomLeversRBox/calculate_probability[calculate_probability])`.

I run `calculate_probability()`.

I receive the following output.

```
[1] "Probability: 0.95"
attr(,"class")
[1] "message"
```

How do I add to generic function print the message method print.message, and print only `Probability: 0.95`?

I have also tried `box::use(TomLeversRBox/calculate_probability[calculate_probability], TomLeversRBox/print.message[print.message])`.

I strongly prefer to only use `box::use(TomLeversRBox/calculate_probability[calculate_probability])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`box::register_S3_method`](https://klmr.me/box/reference/register_S3_method.html) inside the module which defines the S3 method:

```
box::register_S3_method('print', 'message', print.message)
```

(And note that you don’t need to, nor should, export the method. It will be accessible anyway, as long as the module is loaded.)

This is required because there could be ambiguity between the names of different S3 generics, which is why ‘box’ does not try to figure this out by itself. To illustrate, consider the S3 method `print.data.frame`. Based on the name, we would probably assume that it would be a method overriding the generic `print` for the class `data.frame`. But it *could also* be a method overriding the generic `print.data` (if it is defined somewhere), for the S3 class `frame`.

Note that calling `box::register_S3_method` is *only* required when overriding generics that are imported from elsewhere (as is the case for `print`). For generics defined in the same module, there is no ambiguity, so ‘box’ figures out the required S3 definitions itself, e.g.:

```
# some/test.r

#' @export
myprint = function (x) UseMethod('myprint')

myprint.message = function (x) {
    cat('<message:', x, '>\n', sep = '')
}
```

```
box::use(
    some/test,
    TomLeversRBox/calculate_probabilities[calculate_probability],
)

test$myprint(calculate_probability())
# <message:Probability: 0.95>
```

Comment: 1. `install.packages('box', repos = 'https://klmr.r-universe.dev')`.

2. setwd('C:/Users/Tom/Documents/Tom_Levers_Git_Repository')`.

3. file_test('-f', './TomLeversRBox/<calculate_probability and print.message>.R')

4. I confirmed that contents of `calculate_probability.R` are as above without first line and contents of `print.message.R` are as above with the line you provided in lieu of `#' @export`.

5. box::use(TomLeversRBox/calculate_probability[calculate_probability])

6. calculate_probability()

Output:
[1] "Probability: 0.95"
attr(,"class")
[1] "message"

Comment: @TomLever You forgot to also load `TomLeversBox/print.message`!

Comment: The behavior I am going for is as follows. Please note that conflicts with your response.

    # calculate_probability.R
    box::use(./print.message[print.message])
    box::register_S3_method('print', 'message', print.message)
    box::use(stats[pnorm])

    #' @export
    calculate_probability <- function() {
        message <- paste("Probability: ", round(pnorm(1.644854, 0, 1, lower.tail = TRUE), 2), sep = "")
        class(message) <- "message"
        return(message)
    }

    # print.message.R
    print.message <- function(message) {
        cat(message)
    }

Comment: @TomLever That can’t work. The call to `box::register_S3_method` *must* be in the same module that defines the S3 method. Otherwise R won’t find it.

Comment: Simply, it, or its version at the commit below, does work, in RStudio, and I failed with what you proposed. I'm happy to continue here, in a chat, or in an email. See https://github.com/tslever/Tom_Levers_Git_Repository/commit/aee5956f9432f3c1656ca4ebe4f6f1e5b662b7d8#diff-717c57551519392bf3c72334424301b462fa2bfc1e4244cfab4fc0a68063b885.

Comment: @TomLever Interesting. This works only by accident, please don’t rely on it (it might suddenly change in future versions). Additionally, note that you still need to export `print.message` for this to work. In your specific code it works because the `print.message.R` file is a so-called [“legacy module”](https://klmr.me/box/reference/use.html#export-specification), which means that *everything* gets exported automatically.

Comment: With your help, I was able to allow using functions calculate_probability and print.message separately, and print "Probability: 0.95". See https://github.com/tslever/Tom_Levers_Git_Repository/commit/1c710b6694be51171ce77a76dce1128751f6fe71. I'm a little disappointed that using one "make available" statement is discouraged: it is not canonical box to automatically register S3 methods associated with other functions returning objects, and that https://adv-r.hadley.nz/r6.html discourages the use of R6 objects.

Comment: @TomLever What do you mean with “‘make available’ statement”?

Comment: In the case of box, I mean one box::use() statement; I used the concept "make available" to separate this engineering concept from any one software tool.